# Item visibility not working in script

Tags: java, android

I have the following in my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:visibility="gone"
                  android:id="@+id/topNav"
    >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stop_surfing"/>
        <TextView
            style="@style/Counter"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@+id/webview"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the method `surf()`, I was assuming that my linear layout would show, but instead nothing happens. Do I need to do something else to refresh the activity or something?

Here is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Snipped code //
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptBinder(this), "$js");
        // Snipped code //
    }
}
```

And here is the secondary class:

```
public class JavaScriptBinder{

    Activity context;

    JavaScriptBinder(Activity context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void surf(String memberId){
        // Snipped code //
        LinearLayout top = (LinearLayout)context.findViewById(R.id.topNav);
        top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

`surf()` is called from a javascript file loaded in the webview:

```
function startSurfing(){
    var users = document.getElementsByClassName("user");
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        users[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            with(document.getElementById("black-overlay").style){
                display = "block";
                backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)";
            }
            var userId = this.dataset.id;
            $js.surf(userId);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do something other than this. Are you sure you have the right instance of the Activity and that you call that code from the UI Thread?

Comment: @RyanNaddy and when did you call surf?

Comment: I call it from the webview javascript file when an item on the page is clicked `$js.surf(userId);`

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix anything, but besides wondering where surf is called, I'd move `LinearLayout top = (LinearLayout)context.findViewById(R.id.topNav);` into your `onCreate()`.
You may also consider making the `LinearLayout` visible in your `xml` temporarily just to make sure you can actually see it.

Comment: @Steven_BDawg it shows up when I make it visible.

Comment: Okay so last, I'd also try to run `surf()` through your Android code, just to ensure it actually will do what you want once your `javascript` code properly calls it. If `surf()` works, you then know your `$js.surf(userId);` isn't working.

Comment: it works from the js, because I had a `System.out.println("surf()")` in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that the code is run in a different Thread, so of course, you can't update your UI from this method just like this, see here:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

> - JavaScript interacts with Java object on a private, background thread of this WebView. Care is therefore required to maintain thread safety.

So what you need to do, is to run that code in the UI Thread. 
Also, you need to annotate your method with `@JavascriptInterface`, for the method to be callable for Android 4.2 and above.

Try with this:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void surf(String memberId){
    // Snipped code //
    final LinearLayout top = (LinearLayout)context.findViewById(R.id.topNav);
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
       @Override
       public void run(){
          top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
    });

}
```

Comment: That makes it work! on a side note, 1) I had to make top final. 2) You are missing a `)` on the method `runOnUiThread()` but otherwise it works thanks!